# MVC Authorize Redirect to Another Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webmatrix, asp.net-authorization

I use WebMatrix.WebData; In my MVC project, inside controller I wrote this line of code:

```
 [Authorize(Roles ="Members")]
```

When login fails, it will redirect my application to Home/Login. But I want to redirect to Home/Register. How can I do this?

Comment: you should have loginurl in your web.config

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net Identity ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `web forms` you should change your `web.config` file like this.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Register" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

if you are not you can change `LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Register"),` under `ConfigureAuth` method in `Startup class` inside `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs`

Comment: when ım search oginUrl="~/Home/Login" in web config its not find

Comment: @FurkanBozdağ can you post as code or picture your `web.config` file.

Comment: Ok just add `<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Register" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>` part before `</system.web>`

Comment: When ı add it HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Comment: I edited the post. I hope it works now. Good luck :)